# How to enforce table creation order in hibernate

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, h2

I have the following JPA entities

1. `foo_accounts`
2. `foo_account_configurations`

The hibernate ddl is set to auto generate the database schema, but foo_account_configurations is getting created first on spring boot application startup and fails on the FK enforcement.

```
alter table foo_account_configurations 
   add constraint FKtnq5xeucto3vlkd5y243sq411 
   foreign key (foo_account_id) 
   references foo_acc [42102-214]
```

How to enforce table creation order? This error happens **only** with the h2 database and not with the mysql database

Comment: There is probably something wrong with the enities mapping. You should add it

Comment: I have checked the mapping and unable to spot it, is there any other way to pinpoint the error

Comment: Hibernate decides which queries to run based on the mapping. This type of problem can only be one of two things: a bug or something is missing/wrong in the mapping. I'm not sure how you expect us to help you without seeing the model of the two entities involved.